# How to format time column after creating pivot table using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, apache-poi, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table using a existing excel sheet.
But after creating when i check the pivot table in excel it gives some numbers in time column.
I want the time to be in hh:mm format when I open the excel pivot sheet.
Code:

```
try{

            FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\EXCEL JAVA/ecga1.xlsx"));   
            XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
            XSSFSheet sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFSheet pivot_sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.createSheet("MAIN");

            int numColumns = 4;
            int numRows = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
            AreaReference a = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1));
            CellReference b = new CellReference("A1");

            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivot_sheet.createPivotTable(a,b,sheet);
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(3);
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.MIN, 1, "ARRIVAL TIME");
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.MAX, 1, "DEPARTURE TIME");

            FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\EXCEL JAVA/ecga1.xlsx")); 
            my_xlsx_workbook.write(output_file);
            input_document.close(); 
            }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question? please share if possible..thanks